# Are there IMAP/POP3 to MS Graph Mail API proxy?

Tags: email, exchange, proxy

I've got some server product that retrieve emails via POP3/IMAP protocols. Currently switch from Exchange on-prem to Exchange online. Sadly it's not planned to enable POP3/IMAP support anymore even with OAuth authentication. On other hand, we can't change server product directly.

Are there any solution (even half-backed as we could extend/develop) that provides transparent proxy without local storage of emails between these mail protocols?